# Latest OCI SDK documantation page API reference does not list all service clients

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

Latest 2.88.1 (updated 11/15) documentation site under API reference, it does not list all service clients for navigation and search.

[oci sdk 2.88.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.88.0/api/landing.html) lists dozens of service clients.

[oci sdk 2.88.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.88.1/api/landing.html) only lists three service clients.

Need to provide same access as previous version

Comment: I was going to ask what you thought we could do about it and point you to Oracle's feedback mechanisms; but I see that [it says to ask here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.88.1/feedback.html). The GitHub link doesn't seem to show anything related and the developer tools forum link seems to be dead, unhelpfully. The others do still seem to be there, if you do do the 2.88.0 version and change the URL; they just don't seem to be listed/indexed properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed now - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.88.1/api/landing.html

Reference to GitHub issue - https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/issues/495

Thanks for reporting it.